# Flutter WillPopScope works normally for me but when I navigate or push back to the same page it does not work

Tags: android, flutter, dart

My problem is that I have a main page then sign in page then a homepage where if I press logout in the homepage it should navigate me back to the main page which contains the willpopscope , what I'm trying to do is to prevent the user from pressing the back button in the main page so that the app does not return to the homepage without the user being signed in , the problem is that the willpopscope does not work when I Navigator.push the homepage , so whenever I press the back button it returns me to the home page.

I tried changing the position of WillPopScope, If I wrap the whole widget by it , it will never work for me

Code to reproduce

```
//Main page:
class MainActivity extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isWelcome;
  MainActivity(this.isWelcome);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return OperateMainActivity(isWelcome);
  }
}

class OperateMainActivity extends State<MainActivity> {
  bool isWelcome = false;
  OperateMainActivity(this.isWelcome);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //print(isWelcome);
    return MaterialApp(
        home: MyHome(
      isWelcome: isWelcome,
    ));
  }
}

class myHome extends StatelessWidget
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
          child: WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: () async => false,
        child: Container(....)


// Home page

Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainActivity(false)));

//When pushing to main activity WillPopScope does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WillPopScope` doesn't get called when you push. That's the logical behavior, because when you're pushing another view it goes above the current view in the stack. Therefore, the current view never pops out.

If you know that your `MainActivity` is below you're current page in the stack, you could change:

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainActivity(false)));
```

to:

```
Navigator.pop(context); // This will make a call to onWillPop.
```

UPDATE:

For what you want to achieve, you could just use `pushAndRemoveUntil`:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) {
      return MainActivity();
    },
  ),
  (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
);
```

It will push the desired page and remove everything else from the stack.

Comment: Is there any other solution, my case is that if the user is signed in , the user is remembered so the view stack never contains the main page because everything is skipped and the first page shown is the home page

Comment: What's the purpose of the main page? What you need is to go to the main page and remove everything else from the stack?

Comment: The main page is the page which navigates through the application sign in or sign up etc.. once i sign in i go to home page ,, and yes I would like to go to main page and remove everything else from the stack as if I restarted the application